# Finding conditional pdf, conditional expectation, and conditional variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

Given

\begin{align*}
    f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
    2x & \text{ if } 0 < x < 1, \hspace{0.3cm} x < y < x + 1 \\
    0 & \text{ otherwise,}
    \end{cases}
    \end{align*}

(a) Find the conditional pdf $f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)$ of $Y$ given $X = x$.

(b) Find the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X = x]$ of $Y$ given $X = x$

(c) Find the conditional variance $\text{Var}(Y \mid X = x)$ of $Y$ given $X = x$.

---

My try:

(a) $$f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f_{X}(x)} = \frac{2x}{\int_{x}^{x + 1} 2x \mathop{dy}} = \frac{2x}{2x} = 1$$

for $0 < x < 1$

(b) $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X = x]$ is computed as follows:

$$\int_{x}^{x + 1} y \mathop{dy} = \boxed{\frac{2x + 1}{2}}$$

(c) First find the second moment

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^{2} \mid X = x] = \int_{x}^{x + 1} y^{2} \mathop{dy} = \frac{(x + 1)^{3} - x^{2}}{3} = \frac{3x^2 + 3x + 1}{3}$$
Therefore,

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(Y \mid X = x) = \mathbb{E}[Y^2 \mid X = x] - (\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X = x])^{2} = \frac{3x^2 + 3x + 1}{3} - \frac{4x^2 + 4x + 1}{4} 
\end{align*} $$

---

Did I solve this problem correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indicator functions while writing density functions to keep track of the support of the distributions.

One can directly see that the joint density factors as

\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=2x\,\mathbf1_{0<x<1\,,\,x<y<x+1}
\\&=\underbrace{\mathbf1_{x<y<x+1}}_{f_{Y\mid X}(y)}\,\underbrace{2x\,\mathbf1_{0<x<1}}_{f_X(x)}
\end{align}

This shows that $Y\mid X$ has a uniform distribution over $(x,x+1)$ for each $0<x<1$.

It follows that for each $0<x<1$, $$E\left[Y\mid X=x\right]=\frac{2x+1}{2}$$

and $$\operatorname{Var}\left[Y\mid X=x\right]=\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: How do you do it with integration?

Comment: @stackofhay42 Check your integral for $f_X$; you did not evaluate it correctly.

Comment: Oops yeah you're right

Comment: I fixed the integral calculation. It equals $1$. But what are the bounds for $f_{Y \mid X}(x)$? Is it equal to $1$ for $0 < x < 1?$ or $x < y < x + 1$?

Comment: @stackofhay42 That's why it is recommended to use indicator functions while writing pdfs. See my answer. $f_{Y\mid X}(y)$ (its argument is $y$, not $x$ as you wrote in your comment) equals $1$ when $x<y<x+1$ and equals $0$ otherwise, whenever $0<x<1$.

Comment: Okay, I still don't get how you got $\text{Var}(Y \mid X = x)$. My computation aligns with your answer for the expectation now, but not the variance. I've included my new computation in my post now.

Comment: @stackofhay42 You are making careless mistakes. Check your last line.

Comment: Oops I see it now